# Instatiate Object inside for

Tags: java, loops, object, for-loop, new-object

I am instatiating an object outside For and changing value like this:

```
NotaCaract dadosNota = aux.getListaNotasInicial().createNewNotaCaract();

    for(int i=0; i< saida.getListaCompletaProds().size(); i++){

        seqIdNota = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getIdNota().getIntValue();
        dadosNota.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqIdNota);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNota);

        seqNotaDesFornecedor = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqNotaDesFornecedor().getIntValue();
        dadosNota.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqNotaDesFornecedor);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNota);

        seqNotaDesMorada = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqMorada().getIntValue();
        dadosNota.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqNotaDesMorada);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNota);

        seqNotaMoradaFornecedor = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqNotaMoradaFornecedor().getIntValue();
        dadosNota.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqNotaMoradaFornecedor);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNota);

        seqFinalidadeFinanciamento = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqFinalidadeFinanciamento().getIntValue();
        dadosNota.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqFinalidadeFinanciamento);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNota);

        seqJustificacao = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqJustificacao().getIntValue();
        dadosNota.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqJustificacao);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNota);

        seqObservacaoAmbitoProposta = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqObservacaoAmbitoProposta().getIntValue();
        dadosNota.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqObservacaoAmbitoProposta);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNota);

    }
```

Let's suppose only first instance has a value 1 and all other values are 0.
My final List aux.getListaNotasInicial() will be all 0's.

But when i do this:

```
    for(int i=0; i< saida.getListaCompletaProds().size(); i++){

        NotaCaract dadosNota = aux.getListaNotasInicial().createNewNotaCaract();
        seqIdNota = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getIdNota().getIntValue();
        dadosNota.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqIdNota);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNota);

        NotaCaract dadosNotaDesFornecedor = aux.getListaNotasInicial().createNewNotaCaract();
        seqNotaDesFornecedor = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqNotaDesFornecedor().getIntValue();
        dadosNotaDesFornecedor.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqNotaDesFornecedor);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNotaDesFornecedor);

        NotaCaract dadosNotaDesMorada = aux.getListaNotasInicial().createNewNotaCaract();
        seqNotaDesMorada = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqMorada().getIntValue();
        dadosNotaDesMorada.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqNotaDesMorada);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNotaDesMorada);

        NotaCaract dadosNotaMoradaFornecedor = aux.getListaNotasInicial().createNewNotaCaract();
        seqNotaMoradaFornecedor = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqNotaMoradaFornecedor().getIntValue();
        dadosNotaMoradaFornecedor.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqNotaMoradaFornecedor);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNotaMoradaFornecedor);

        NotaCaract dadosNotaFinalidadeFinanciamento = aux.getListaNotasInicial().createNewNotaCaract();
        seqFinalidadeFinanciamento = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqFinalidadeFinanciamento().getIntValue();
        dadosNotaFinalidadeFinanciamento.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqFinalidadeFinanciamento);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNotaFinalidadeFinanciamento);

        NotaCaract dadosNotaJustificacao = aux.getListaNotasInicial().createNewNotaCaract();
        seqJustificacao = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqJustificacao().getIntValue();
        dadosNotaJustificacao.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqJustificacao);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNotaJustificacao);

        NotaCaract dadosNotaObservacaoAmbitoProposta = aux.getListaNotasInicial().createNewNotaCaract();
        seqObservacaoAmbitoProposta = saida.getListaCompletaProds().getDadosCompletosProd(i).getProdutosLeasing().getSeqObservacaoAmbitoProposta().getIntValue();
        dadosNotaObservacaoAmbitoProposta.getIdNota().setIntValue(seqObservacaoAmbitoProposta);
        aux.getListaNotasInicial().addNotaCaract(dadosNotaObservacaoAmbitoProposta);

    }
```

My final list aux.getListaNotasInicial() will have exactly the values i want it to have. Why do i have to instatiate multiple objects inside loop to use their values, when i could just instatiate only 1 and change his value as i wish?

PS: My platform only supports Java 6
Ty

Comment: In the first case you store multiple references to the _same_ object in the list. And this one and only object can only hold a single value, either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate an object, you are reserving a memory location and storing that object in it (along with its values). So for example, in your first case, you instantiate only one object, and reserve one memory location for it. When you instantiate only one object and change values for it, every time you change the value you are **overwriting** the value.

Furthermore, when you only declare one instance of the object and add it to an array multiple times, you are in essence adding the same object (memory location). Therefore, your array will only contain the last known modification to the object because all previous data was overwritten. This is why you have to declare multiple instances of the object so you reserve multiple memory locations and save all the different values.